# How can I create a disclaimer?

Tags: email, legal

I am trying to email certain companies with requests of donations (physical products, not money) to my organisation. However, my organisation has not had many real discussions about any of this, and therefore I don't want to come across as representing the organisation I attend. I just want to inquire as to whether or not there is a possibility of a donation before I suggest an idea that will probably fail to my organisation.

How can I write a disclaimer that gets this point across - are there example of disclaimers to fit certain situations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18872/discussion-between-chris-lively-and-tim).

Comment: You need to find a lawyer.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. "with requests *of* donations": do you mean "with requests *for* donations"? *For* and *from* what organization and location are you doing the requests? What email address are you using? Please [edit ypur question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/36553/edit)

Comment: @Tim something new learned; saves a lot of time because I always make it a link ;-)

Comment: @Jan Picked those up on [ubuntu.se]! You can also do `[workplace.se]` to go to [workplace.se], and `[ubuntu.se]` to [ubuntu.se]! All useful tricks to save time! I've edited - hope that helps!

Comment: `I didn't do it, no one saw me do it, you can't prove anything!` - Bart Simpson

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding of what's going on is:

- The OP is affiliated with some organization
- That organization has *not* discussed the idea of seeking donations
- The OP, in an effort to help, wants to contact other companies to see if they would be willing to donate products.
- The OP, thinks a disclaimer is necessary.

If the above is true then what you should do is:

- Do Not take any action until you have discussed it first with your organization.  There *may* be legal, tax or some other regulatory impact that you are not aware of that may prevent them from being a beneficiary of donations.  You'll want this explored by the organization before you start asking.
- You should make these inquiries while acting as a representative of the organization.  (see step 1) Honestly, a phone call is best as an email coming from an account that is not directly tied to the organization is likely to simply be ignored.  By calling the companies directly you can better explain what it is you are trying to do.  As @keshlam said, you risk burning bridges doing this solo.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't represent the organization, you probably shouldn't be soliciting on its behalf. You risk burning goodwill that they may need for other solicitations.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you decide to go along with this plan, and we help you write a disclaimer. You use this to let people know that you are not acting in the interest of company x.

Unfortunately if company x doesn't review and approve your disclaimer it only tells people that company x doesn't represent you. If company x thinks it is poorly written and somebody gets upset, or misunderstands your discussion, company x can sue you or fire you for misrepresenting them.

Yes getting your lawyer involved will help, but untimely they will tell you to get the company to write it to protect you from future problems.